# Factory_boy not creating RelatedFactory in Trait

Tags: python, django, factory-boy

I've got a `Purchase` model and a `PurchaseInfo` model. `PurchaseInfo` has a foreign key to `Purchase`. I'm trying to modify an existing Factory for `Purchase` that will create `PurchaseInfo` at the same time using `RelatedFactory` since it's a reverse foreign key relationship. The only thing is that I wanted to use a Taint so that I could control the value of fields within `PurchaseInfo`. Normally when I create a `Purchase` like `p = PurchaseFactory()` the `PurchaseInfo` is created with null fields inside of it. If I create a `Purchase` like `p = PurchaseFactory(info=True)`, so I can get the field modifications via the Taint, the `PurchaseInfo` is not created at all.

I have a feeling that putting the `RelatedFactory` in a Taint is not the way to go. What is the correct way to do this?

Models:

```
class Purchase(Model):
    ...

class PurchaseInfo(Model):
    purchase = models.ForeignKey(Purchase, on_delete=models.CASCADE, unique=True, db_index=True)
    lock = DateTimeField(null=True)
    lock_by = ForeignKey(...
```

```
class PurchaseInfoFactory(DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = PurchaseInfoField

    lock = None
    lock_by = None

class PurchaseFactory(DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = Purchase

    info = RelatedFactory(PurchaseInfoFactory,
                          factory_related_name='purchase')

    class Params:
        info = Trait(internalfield=RelatedFactory(PurchaseInfoFactory,
                                                  factory_related_name='purchase',
                                                  lock=timezone.now() - relativedelta(months=1),
                                                  lock_by=SubFactory(UserFactory, user_id=1)))
```

Comment: Have you tried `SubFactory` for this??

Comment: Try to use a different name for the trait

Comment: @bdbd, you mean the "info = " line, right? I did try that.

Comment: @Sabil I don't think a `SubFactory` can be used here. The SubFactory will be created first before the parent and I can't pass the parent's ID into it because it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like my solution, but here's what I did. I derived a secondary factory with an alternate RelatedFactory. That works.

```
class PurchaseFactory(DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = Purchase

    info = RelatedFactory(PurchaseInfoFactory,
                          factory_related_name='purchase')
```

```
class InfoPurchaseFactory(DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = Purchase

    info = Trait(internalfield=RelatedFactory(PurchaseInfoFactory,
                                                  factory_related_name='purchase',
                                                  lock=timezone.now() - relativedelta(months=1),
                                                  lock_by=SubFactory(UserFactory, user_id=1)))
```